# What timezone is startTime and endTime of the VacationSettings type for the Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I can see that `startTime` and `endTime` are in `epoch ms` but I can't figure out what Timezone everything is in?

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/VacationSettings

Is it the user's timezone according to their Gmail calendar or Google's backend or GMT/UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in "epoch ms" which is unixtime, and is the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, UTC.

"epoch ms" uses the UTC timezone.

All the displayed dates/times are converted according to user preferences/location, but have no effect on the stored data.

Comment: Got it. So I need to convert before I make  the call. Thank you!

Comment: Yep. It is a good general practice for storing dates, since you know that you *always* need to convert input data to epoch ms and *always* need to convert epoch ms to localtime. If you ever store localtime, you'll never be sure what the data really means if any of the users cross timezones.